# Getting Unusual error with Pandas for a regression learning program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, quandl

```
import pandas as pandas 
import Quandl as Quandl

df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

print (df.head)
```

when i try to run this program it generates an unusual error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/machine/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: /home/machine/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ML_prac.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pandas 
  File "/home/machine/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: /home/machine/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

What should i do to fix this issue??? Any Suggestions

Comment: How did you install panda? Was it a manual build?

Comment: yup i installed it through 'pip'

Comment: Try uninstalling pandas and its dependencies, mainly numpy, and then reinstall pandas and let it handle installing of numpy.

Comment: thanks mate this works.

Comment: @LuckyAnsari since this was  an install issue and solved can you delete question.

Comment: @kaveh : darn the issue is back, as i restarted the computer the new installation is showing the same problem.

Comment: hey i force removed an lock on the 'apt-get ', and then i reconfigured the 'dpkg', could that cause this problem to occur again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade using pip --

```
[sudo] pip install --upgrade pandas
```